# Qt Property Browser Framework or similar in python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am using pyqt for one of my projects and need a property browser similar to the one provided by qtdesigner supporting hierarchical properties:

[image: Qt Designer Property Editor]

I have found that Qt supports a [Property Browser Framework](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq18-propertybrowser.html) but couldn't find it in pyqt so I jumped to the conclusion that pyqt does not support this framework.

Does pyqt support this framework or something similar? Or should I start coding this from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those of you landing here, I was able to roll my own solution based on the `pyqtgraph`'s `Parameter Tree` which forms a solid basis for such purposes in my own opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The Property Browser Framework is part of Qt Solutions, and not part of the main Qt Toolkit. I'm not sure of the full history of Qt Solutions, but I think it was dropped from the SDK after Digia took over from Nokia. Anyway, all the Qt Solutions classes are now deprecated, and there's no real development done on them anymore.

There was never any plan to include the Qt Solutions classes in PyQt - although I suppose a websearch might find some third-party libraries that are still being maintained, if you're really keen to use them. Probably wiser to just roll your own solution, though...

Comment: ended up rolling my own solution, thanks for the info

Comment: I am also loking for a Property Browser View. How did you made your own?

Comment: @zalavari Please see my answer below